# Angular Wiring up two controllers from Model to auto fill form

Tags: angularjs, bootstrap-modal

I've got an angular app I'm working on where I'm trying to auto fill a pop up modal based on a user's selection.

I thought I could use my model service to keep track of what the user selected and 'wire' the controller for the `<select>` list and it's edit button to the model but that doesn't seem to work.

Adding to the complexity I'm using angular-route and my `<select>` list is buried in a view. I was trying to keep my pop up modals in a separate controller outside the view because they've got their own templates and I had problems when I nested them into the view...

I've seen a few examples of wiring up angular apps and thought I understood them but I can't figure out what I'm doing wrong.

EDIT (thanks Pankaj Parkar for pointed out my mistakes in the plunker):

I have a plunker here:

https://plnkr.co/edit/6f9FZmV8Ul6LZDm9rcg9?p=preview

Below is the snipped in a single HTML page with CDN links :).

Am I just completely misunderstanding how angularjs is suppose to work?

```
<html ng-app="myApp">

    <head>
        <title>Bootstrap 3</title>
    </head>
    <meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width, initial-scale=1.0"/>
    <link href="https://maxcdn.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/3.3.7/css/bootstrap.min.css" rel="stylesheet"/>


    <body>

        <div ng-view></div> 

        <script id="editables.html" type="text/ng-template">
            <div class="container">
                <div class="jumbotron">

                    <form>
                        <div class="form-group">
                            <select class="form-control" id="mapsSelect" size="10" multiple ng-model="model.selected">
                                <option ng-repeat="n in editables">{{n}}</option>
                            <select>
                        </div>

                        <a href="#editModal" class = "btn btn-info" data-toggle="modal" ng-click="edit()" >Edit</a>

                    </form>

                </div>      
            </div><!--end container div-->      
        </script>

        <div ng-controller="modalsController">
            <div id="editModal" class="modal fade" role="dialog">
                <div class="modal-dialog">
                    <div class="modal-content">
                        <form class="form-horizontal">
                            <div class="modal-header">
                                <button type="button" class="close" data-dismiss="modal" aria-hidden="true">&times;</button>
                                <h4>New Map</h4>
                            </div>
                            <div class="modal-body">

                                <div class="form-group">
                                    <label for="name" class="col-lg-3 control-label">Name</label>
                                    <div class="col-lg-9">
                                        <input type="text" class="form-control" id="name" ng-model="formModel.name"></input>
                                    </div>
                                </div>

                                <div class="form-group">
                                    <label for="desc" class="col-lg-3 control-label">Description</label>
                                    <div class="col-lg-9">
                                        <input type="text" class="form-control" id="desc" ng-model="formModel.desc"></input>
                                    </div>
                                </div>


                            <div class="modal-footer">

                                <pre> {{ formModel | json }}<br><br>Working: {{ workingMap }}</pre>

                                <a href="#" class="btn btn-primary pull-right" data-dismiss="modal">Cancel</a>
                                <a href="#" class="btn btn-success fcvt-btn-save fcvt-btn-continue"">Continue</a>
                            </div>
                        </form>
                    </div>
                </div>
            </div><!-- end modal -->
        </div>

    </body>

    <script src = "https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/3.1.0/jquery.min.js"></script>
    <script src = "https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/angularjs/1.5.7/angular.min.js"></script>
    <script src = "https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/angular.js/1.6.1/angular-route.min.js"></script>  
    <script src = "https://maxcdn.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/3.3.7/js/bootstrap.min.js"></script>

    <!-- <script src = "js/script.js"></script> -->

    <script>

        var app = angular.module('myApp', ['ngRoute']);

        var modelService =  function ($log){

            var moduleHello = function(myMessage){
                console.log("Module hellow from myService "  + myMessage);
            }

            var moduleNames = {

                "First" : {desc: "First's Description"},
                "Second" : {desc: "Second's Description"},
                "Third" : {desc: "Third's Description"}

            };

            var moduleWorkingName = {};

            return {
                hello: moduleHello,
                editables: moduleNames,
                workingName: moduleWorkingName
            }

        }//end modelService

        app.factory("modelService", ["$log", modelService]);

        app.config(['$routeProvider', function($routeProvider) {

                $routeProvider.
                when('/editables', {
                    controller: "editablesController",
                    templateUrl: "editables.html"
                }).
                otherwise({
                    redirectTo: "/editables"
                });

        }]);

        app.controller('editablesController', ['$scope', '$log','modelService', function($scope,$log, $modelService) {

                $scope.model = {};

                //console.log( JSON.stringify( $modelService.editables ) );

                $scope.editables = [];

                for ( name in $modelService.editables){
                    $scope.editables.push( name );
                }

                $scope.edit = function(){

                    if ( typeof $modelService.editables [$scope.model.selected] != 'undefined'){
                        $modelService.workingName = $modelService.editables [$scope.model.selected];            
                        console.log ("Setting my working name to " + JSON.stringify( $modelService.workingName ) );
                    }else{
                        console.log ("Nothing Selected");
                    }

                }
        }]);

        app.controller('modalsController', ['$scope','modelService', function($scope,$modelService) {

            $scope.formModel = {};

            $scope.formModel.name =  "Hard coding works of course";
            $scope.formModel.desc = $modelService.workingName.desc; //But I can't seem to get this to update. I thought pointing it at an object in the Model would be enough.

            console.log("Firing up modalsController");

        }]);

    </script>

</html>
```

Answer (score 1):

I spent the last two days mulling over this in my head and I think I figured it out. For starters, here's the (working) plunker:

https://plnkr.co/edit/Kt3rebPtvGTt0WMXkQW4?p=preview

Now, the explanation. I was trying to keep a separate 'formModel' object that kept track of the controller's state. But that's both silly and pointless.

Instead what you're supposed to do is:

a. Create an object in your service to hold all your data (I just called this 'model')

b. For each controller that needs to share data create a variable on the `$scope` of the controller and point it to your 'model' variable from your service.

c. after that use the variables from your model in your html.

So in both my controllers you'll find this line:

```
$scope.model = $modelService.model;
```

and in my HTML you'll find stuff like this:

```
<input type="text" class="form-control" id="name" ng-model="model.workingName.name"></input>
```

notice how I'm using "model.workingName.name"? This references  `$scope.model.workingName.name`, which thanks to the line `$scope.model = $modelService.model` from my JavaScript now points directly to my model.

And that is how you "wire up" Angular.

By the way, experienced Angular folks have probably noticed that this part:

```
    $scope.editables = [];

    for ( name in $modelService.model.names){
        $scope.editables.push( name );
    }
```

probably belongs in a directive instead of a controller because I'm editing the DOM.

Stuff like that's what makes it so hard to learn AngularJS. There's so many concepts to get the hang of.

Comment: One more thing I've learned along the way:

If you've got a dialog/modal with save/cancel buttons don't wire it directly to your model (e.g. don't use your model's variables in your ng-model directives). That's when you need a 'formSettings' object. Then you use ng-click to do save/cancel operations that copy it to your model (or reset the form to what's currently in the model).